# CKeditor 4 Disable Profanity filter

Tags: ckeditor, profanity

Hello and thank you for your time.  I have an issue where partial of a phone number is being replaced with asterisks (8008).  I've tried to add config.allowedContent multiple places but it hasn't fixed the issue.  Is there a file somewhere with a list of words that it checks for filtration?

Thanks for the help

Comment: `allowedContent` is not the problem; the [docs](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_allowed_content_rules.html) state "Allowed Content Rules define which HTML elements, attributes, styles, and classes are allowed."  Can you provide more detail on when the asterisks appear?  Are you setting the editor and asterisks are displayed instead of 8008? Are asterisks returned from `getData()` after you type 8008?  Do asterisks replace 8009 or 9009 or 808?

Comment: Yes <code>getData()</code> is being called before the final submit.

Comment: You only answered 1 of my questions.  I'm trying to help you, work with me.  Are you typing 8008, is the the content being set programmatically, or are you using CKEditor to edit existing content on the page?  Do the asterisks appear on-screen or only in the content returned by `getData()`?  If it's the latter you can set a breakpoint when you call `getData()` and step through CKEditor's code to see why the asterisks are appearing.

Comment: Forgive me.  Content is being entered through the editor. It is being physically typed out and appears properly.  When saved and returned through the getData() is when data comes back with asterisks. Doesn't appear till page is refreshed since data is being passed to sql through ajax.

Comment: What is being sent to the server, 8008 or asterisks?  What is being returned from the server, 8008 or asterisks?  Are other numbers similarly affected, like 8009 or 808 or 80008?